# Retrieving only enabled accounts on active directory

Tags: java, active-directory

I'd like to send a search string to Microsoft's Active Directory (using Java) that says "give me all the users who have an enabled account."

Currently, I have:

String search_string = "(& (objectClass=user) )";

but, of course, this only give me the users on AD. I'd like to also get only those who are active. It's in Java, but I don't think it matters for LDAP.

Comment: You need to figure out what 'active' means in your context and code the appropriate LDAP query.  Since you haven't defined what 'active' means, I doubt anybody here can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What portion of the code determines how 'active' is defined? (Normally, I create an LDAP Property object which gets filled with username, password, and host info to get the AD connection. Then, I create the context and the Search Query and get my response from AD. I'm a little confused with defining what 'active' means.) Could you elucidate? (I could supply my code, but I don't know what portions would be considered relevant.)

Comment: You have to decide, for yourself, what YOU mean by "active" and how that maps to an LDAP attribute that you can query.  We do not know what you mean by "active" in your context.

Comment: Let me know if I'm misunderstanding you entirely, but what I mean is Microsoft's Active Directory. I'm connecting to the server and giving the search query described above.

Comment: What do YOU mean by the word "active"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to get the enabled users you must check the userAccountControl attribute and specifically its second bit, which corresponds to ACCOUNTDISABLE flag. [MS KB 305144](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144).

This can be done with LDAP filter like this:

```
(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
```

Check this article about [Filtering for Bit Fields](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Filtering%20for%20Bit%20Fields) for details on how this work.

Also you should know that computer accounts are inherited from the user type, so you should add a condition in you filter, to filter them out. You also may want to check the bit for NORMAL_ACCOUNT flag (512), to filter other kind of accounts.

I do not know what do you mean by active users, so I cannot help you there.

Answer (score 4):

Here is as far as I understand the Active-Directory critaria to check if an account is *active* or not.

[How to use the UserAccountControl flags to manipulate user account properties](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144/en-us) gives you the state of an account, you may be interested in :

- ACCOUNTDISABLE (2)
- LOCKOUT        (16)

To use this field in a filter you can use LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN OID, as discribed in [Microsoft article Search Filter Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:=18)))
```